# DNN 7.2.2. Admin appearing as child node of Site

Tags: admin, dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN 7.2.2

I just found out that Admin (and all its children nodes) is appearing as child node of my site tree - I saw that under Page management. Is that normal?

I don't remember Admin as this structure.

Can anyone please tell me how I an move it?

Of course I tried through Page Settings but it's parent is none selected.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal in DNN. In the old days it would actually show up by default in your Menu structure on every page.